# OpenERP Jasper Reports import external library

Tags: java, jasper-reports, odoo

I use OpenERP with Jasper Report module.
The problem is to get amount of generated pages in words. So I found the solution: import in iReport my own library in *.jar file and use some methods from it. But I get some problems.
Аpparently, iReport's classpath to libraries didn't used in Jasper Reports in OpenERP and I always get 'Unable to resolve class' exception.
I tryed to copy *.jar in 'jasper_reports/java/lib' folder, but it ineffectually.
Maybe someone faced to this problem?
And the question is: How to import my own java libraries in japser_reports?
Or, ideally, get another way to print amount of pages in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your java class without a package. Put in a JAR file and set it up.